# How can I automatically hibernate and reawaken my Ubuntu server?

Tags: hibernate, ubuntu, server

I have an Ubuntu 10.10 machine which is supposed to be a server. It only uses about 150W to run, but electricity is not free :( Nobody actually uses it during the night, and I would like to make it auto-hibernate and auto-wake. I know about the `rtcwake` command, but i am not sure how to make it auto-hibernate.

Can anyone point me some ideas about how to this? Like setting it to hibernate every day at 10:00 PM and wake up at 6:45 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times

Basically, the solution is to use `rtcwake` with the `--mode` option. Here is the description from `man rtcwake`:

```
-m mode | --mode mode
  Use standby state mode. Valid values are:

    standby  ACPI state S1. This state offers minimal, though real, power savings,
             while providing a very low-latency transition back to a  working
             system. This is the default mode.

    mem      ACPI state S3 (Suspend-to-RAM). This state offers significant power
             savings as everything in the system is put into a low-power state,
             except for memory, which is placed in self-refresh mode to retain
             its contents.

    disk     ACPI state S4 (Suspend-to-disk). This state offers the greatest power
             savings, and can be used even in the absence of low-level platform
             support for power management. This state operates similarly to
             Suspend-to-RAM, but includes a final step of writing memory contents
             to disk.

    off      ACPI state S5 (Poweroff). This is done by calling  '/sbin/shutdown'.
             Not officially supported by ACPI, but usually working.
```